# Invalid char array assignment

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char name[30][50];
    char aux[50];
    int n,ok;

    cout<<"number of pupils : ";
    cin>>n; 

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"name : ";
        cin>>name[i];
    }

    do
    {
        ok=0;

        for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(name[i],name[i+1])>0)
            {
                aux=name[i+1];   // here is the bug
                name[i+1]=name[i];
                name[i]=aux;
                ok=1;
            }
        }
    }while(ok==1);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<name[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

I know it is a noob question, but I am grateful for your help. How can I assign a char[][] to a char[] ? this error occurs 3 times in my code and I do not have enough knowledge to figure it out why

Comment: Arrays are not assignable. Use std::vector.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: thanks @NeilButterworth

Comment: but how do I use std::vector @NeilButterworth

Comment: Have you tried using strcpy() instead of assigning one array directly to another?

Comment: No, but I will @kylew

Comment: @kylew you are the best, Thanks a lot for solving my homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `char* aux;` instead.**

When we write `char aux[50];`, we are immediately allocating memory for ~50 `char`s. Here you're only swapping pointers *to* the `char` arrays (elements in the array of `char` array, i.e. 2D `char` array called `name`), so a `char*` is what you're looking for.

If you are okay with using the standard library, use `std::swap` like so:

```
std::swap(name[i], name[i + 1]);
```

Comment: @RaresMatei My pleasure! Please accept the answer that best suits what you’re asking.